# Need to display the supported locale date format

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, date, datetime

Im trying to get a list of all the date formats salesforce expects for all the supported locales in my org.  I already have the list of locales codes displayed on a visualforce page. I just need the date formats. Is there a way to get this?
The formats I have are incorrect.

Update:  Im asking  where can I get the dateformats I want to add a new locale to my map or is there a way I can write  apex to just spit out all the date formats for me so I can update this map with the correct format versus referring to  this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=0.

I want to do something like this solution https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/23908/50846 but with the date formats also.

Example below:

en_US(locale) = mm/dd/yyyy(date format)

Answer (score 1):

Someone had Already answered your question :- [Get dateformat based on Locale](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133534/get-dateformat-based-on-locale) . You might need to keep an eye on salesforce new releases if they add new timeZones or change date format.

Comment: Yes I've have seen this.  I guess I wasn't clear. SInce there have been more timezones since that was created where can I find the latest date formats so I can add to my list?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=0 did you had a look at this document?

Comment: yes that's what I've been using.

Comment: I also wants to know what is your use case. I think for most of cases list of locales should be enough

Comment: use case is if a user enters a date manually or by selecting from a datepicker in the correct format.  The issue is for some locales its  giving some users invalid date error.